# why do rails have nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Learning rails and came across this nested resources in routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

Given that there is an association between posts and comments ( a post has many comments, a comment belongs to a post), I can kind of see the association in a similar fashion in the above code

but why do we need nested resources as oppose to simply declaring

```
resources :posts
resources :commments
```

Are the two the same in some aspects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you want to have your users navigate to:

```
# GET
http://yoursite.com/posts/1/comments
```

This would allow you to view a list of comments associated to a post with an ID of 1.

You need to use the below to do this:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

However, if you had the below routes:

```
resources :posts
resources :commments
```

You would have to pass a param and it would look something like:

```
# Get
http://yoursite.com/comments/?post=1
```

The first approach makes it more simple and neater!

## Update:

You can read heaps about routing on [the Rails manual](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). There's also a specific section for [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Answer (score 1):

For associations it is advisable to use nested routing. It's common to have resources that are logically children of other resources. For example, suppose your application includes these models:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

Nested routes allow you to capture this relationship in your routing. In this case, you could include this route declaration:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

Then 
GET

```
/magazines/:magazine_id/ads
```

display a list of all ads for a specific magazine